# Why does adding sugar/salt causes water to release?

Tags: sugar, salt, science

This is purely practical observation.

If I add pinch of sugar or salt, somehow automagically water appears in the pot. For example I had a week old cauliflower somewhat wilted/dried in fridge cooing in a pot - no water added at all. Starting process was basically Indian style "tadka"

Florets were somewhat browning because of heat, but after adding pinch of salt, it sort of became moist or water appeared in the pot. I have similar observations of similar effects for adding sugar too.

What causes it? Where does it get water from if I have not added any water or

Comment: Similar question on the chemistry site: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/96976/how-does-salt-push-out-the-water-from-vegetables-meat-etc

Comment: I've removed some answer-in-comments discussion; please just write an answer if you want to answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salting (sugar coating) the surface of the vegetables; causes [Osmosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmosis).

Water molecules inside the fruit, will move from lower concentration of solvent (salt/sugar) to a higher concentration medium (outside of the fruit)